# Create/Insert in Laravel, Vue + InertiaJS

Tags: php, insert, laravel-10

I'm new to laravel, apologies for that. I want to insert a data into my database in laravel. I watched tutorials in youtube but still I can't figure this out.

Code in my controller:

```
public function __invoke(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'animal_species_id' => 'required|string|uuid',
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'icon' => ['nullable', 'image', 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,webp|size:2048'],
        ]);

        AnimalBreed::create([
            'animal_species_id' => $request->animal_species_id,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'icon' => $request->file('icon') ? $request->file('icon') : null,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('petcheckr.config.animal-breeds.index')
            ->with('flash.message', 'Animal Breed successfully created!');
    }
}
```

after clicking the button it create the data redirect to index with the successful message"

in my Request I have this code:

```
class StoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return !empty($this->user()) && in_array(
            $this->user()->role,
            [
                'PETCHECKR.ADMIN',
                'VET_PRACTICE.ADMIN',
            ]
        );
    }

 public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'animal_species_id' => 'required|string|uuid',
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'image', 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,webp|size:2048'],
        ];
    }
```

It's for the validation.

I think I do double validation?

No error in logs, in inspect network it gives me error 302 in animal-breed, then 200 in create.

I checked the routes if it is working, and it redirects properly but when I implement the entire code it doesn't, there's something wrong somewhere.